# MySQL - Poor performance in a select from a simple table

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a very simple table with three columns:

```
- A BigINT,
- Another BigINT,
- A string.
```

The first two columns are defined as INDEX and there are no repetitions. Moreover, both columns have values in a growing order.

The table has nearly 400K records.

I need to select the string when a value is within those of column 1 and two, in order words:

```
SELECT MyString 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE Col_1       <= Test_Value 
   AND Test_Value  <= Col_2       ;
```

The result may be either a NOT FOUND or a single value.

The query takes nearly a whole second while, intuitively (imagining a binary search throughout an array), it should take just a small fraction of a second.

I checked the index type and it is BTREE for both columns (1 and 2).

Any idea how to improve performance?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The explain reads:

Select type: Simple,
Type: Range,
Possible Keys: PRIMARY
Key: Primary,
Key Length: 8,
Rows: 441,
Filtered: 33.33,
Extra: Using where.

Comment: have compound index?

Comment: It's necessary to show your exact table structure and indexes when seeking performance advice. It's also helpful to use the EXPLAIN command to get the query planner to describe what it's doing. Please [edit] your question to include these items.

Comment: No compound index @YOU.

Comment: @OllieJones, I think that the information I provided is completely clear. The table is exactly as described (3 columns, 1st and 2nd are indexed, etc.). Added the results of the explain though.

Comment: 7 hours later http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464

Comment: I am pretty sure that the fastest way to get the data is a simple full table scan. I cannot imagine an index to really help here. To compare one column to be in a range of two *fixed* numbers is best be done with a binary search, yes, but to check the relation of three columns is definitely not. Maybe it's even a problem that MySQL is using an index here though. (And one second to scan a 400k table is not that slow, anyway.) If you want this query to be faster, then you could add a stored generated column telling you whether `Col_1 <= Test_Value <= Col_2` or not.

Comment: Hey @Drew. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll keep it in mind for future questions.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner for your reply. Just few comments: 1) 1 second for a select is an **eternity**. 2) If I understood your comment, you got it the other way: I'm testing a variable vis-à-vis the values of the two columns in a row and hence saving a result makes no sense, 3) Though need further tests, it would appear that the suggestion made by Rick makes sense and (at least in a small test) is giving significantly better performance. Will need further test though.

Comment: @FDavidov: While I disagree with a second being awfully long for a query to run (that really depends on the query and data), your are right, I misread the problem. And given that there are no overlaps, Rick's limit query is the straight-forward solution. You are aware that there are no overlaps, which the DBMS is not. So using this knowledge as in Rick's query is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner for your comment. Of course, my expectation for this to take a small fraction of a second is based on the fact that the data is extremely simple and there are quite good conditions to achieve a very efficient mechanism (as stated, if I could hold the data in an array on memory, I could write a simple piece of code that would complete the job in less than 1ms. Rick's suggestion appears and not suitable because the lack of pre-defined max range.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your obfuscation correctly, you have a `start` and `end` value such as a datetime or an ip address in a pair of columns?  And you want to see if your given datetime/ip is in the given range?

Well, there is no way to generically optimize such a query on such a table.  The optimizer does not know whether a given value could be in multiple ranges.  Or, put another way, whether the ranges are disjoint.

So, the optimizer will, at best, use an index starting with either `start` or `end` and scan half the table.  Not efficient.

Are the ranges non-overlapping?  [*IP Addresses*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ip-range-table-performance/)

What can you say about the result?  Perhaps a kludge like this will work:  `SELECT ... WHERE Col_1 <= Test_Value ORDER BY Col_1 DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Thank you @RickJames for your answer. I would appear that adding the `ORDER` and `LIMIT` is making a significant difference. Would need further tests though. Will update when conclusive results are achieved. As per IP-Address, no, but much like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your query, rewritten with shorter identifiers, is this

```
SELECT s FROM t WHERE t.low <= v AND v <= t.high
```

To satisfy this query using indexes would go like this: First we must search a table or index for all rows matching the first of these criteria

```
  t.low <= v
```

We can think of that as a half-scan of a BTREE index. It starts at the beginning and stops when it gets to `v`.

It requires another half-scan in *another index* to satisfy `v <= t.high`.  It then requires a merge of the two resultsets to identify the rows matching both criteria. The problem is, the two resultsets to merge are large, and they're almost entirely non-overlapping.

So, the query planner probably should just choose a full table scan instead to satisfy your criteria. That's especially true in the case of MySQL, where the query planner isn't very good at using more than one index.

You may, or may not, be able to speed up this exact query with a compound index on `(low, high, s)` -- with your original column names `(Col_1, Col_2, MyString)`. This is called a [covering index](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/) and allows MySQL to satisfy the query completely from the index. It sometimes helps performance. (It would be easier to guess whether this will help if the exact definition of your table were available; the efficiency of covering indexes depends on stuff like other indexes, primary keys, column size, and so forth. But you've chosen minimal disclosure for that information.)

What will really help here? Rethinking your algorithm could do you a lot of good.  It seems you're trying to retrieve rows where a test point `v` lies in the range [`t.low`, `t.high`].  Does your application offer an a-priori limit on the width of the range? That is, is there a known maximum value of `t.high - t.low`? If so, let's call that value `maxrange`.  Then you can rewrite your query like this:

```
 SELECT s
   FROM t 
  WHERE t.low BETWEEN v-maxrange AND v
    AND t.low <= v AND v <= t.high
```

When `maxrange` is available we can add the `col BETWEEN const1 AND const2` clause. That turns into an efficient range scan on an index on `low`. In that case, the covering index I mentioned above will certainly accelerate this query.

Read this. http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Many thanks @OllieJones or the detailed explanation (and the time spent phrasing it!). Some comments: 1) I wasn't hiding information at all. The table is **exactly** as described (two BigInt columns and a string with index on the first two columns); 2) Unfortunately, there is no pre-defined range for the difference between max and min (i.e. `t.high - t.low`); 3) The test value `v` is a randomly generated number.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found a suitable solution for me (not sure your guys will like it but, as stated, it works for me).

I simply partitioned my 400K records into a number of tables and created a simple table that serves as a selector:

The selector table holds the minimal value of the first column for each partition along with a simple index (i.e. 1, 2, ,...).

I then user the following to get the index of the table that is supposed to contain the searched for range like:

```
SELECT Table_Index 
  FROM tbl_selector 
 WHERE start_range <= Test_Val
 ORDER BY start_range DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

This will give me the Index of the table I wish to select from.

I then have a CASE on the retrieved Index to select the correct partition table from perform the actual search.

(I guess that more elegant would be to use Dynamic SQL, but will take care of that later; for now just wanted to test the approach).

The result is that I get the response well below a second (~0.08) and it is uniform regardless of the number being used for test. This, by the way, was not the case with the previous approach: There, if the number was "close" to the beginning of the table, the result was produced quite fast; if, on the other hand, the record was near the end of the table, it would take several seconds to complete).

[By the way, I assume you understand what I mean by **beginning** and **end** of the table]

Again, I'm sure people might dislike this, but it does the job for me.

Thank you all for the effort to assist!!